# Azure Mobile App Service Authentication Android

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services

We added authentication to our App and are using the offline sync table. But every time we call the sync() method, we get a MobileServicePushFailedException and on the Server we can find an Error 403 (Forbidden request)
The thing is that table access is currently set to anonymous access, so everyone should be able to write on the table when calling the service.
We figured out that after calling the authenticate() method in Android we get a social user ID like this from the client after logging in:

```
mClient.getCurrentUser().getUserId()
```

And in our Node.js backend we tried to extract the user id in the insert method like this:

```
context.item.userid = context.user.id;
```

From those two methods **we get different SID's** and I'm pretty sure that this shouldn't be the case? Anyway we need a way to make offline sync work asap

Comment: We figured out, that table access *MAY NOT be set to anonymous access*, when authentication is enabled. But still we have the problem that we *get different SIDs*